# Google API - mapping 500 coordinates

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I'm working on a project where I have a need to draw a map with a little over 500 points on it.  The code I have works well up to 250 points.  But when I have all 500 coordinates in the XML file that it parses, no points end up displaying on the map.

I imagine there is some kind of throttling that is causing it to fail but I can't figure out how to include this in the code.

Any ideas?

**locations.xml (abbreviated)**

```
<markers>
  <marker name="" address="800 Occidental Ave S  Seattle, WA 98134" lat="47.595091" lng="-122.333229" type="location" />
  <marker name="" address="Bridge Street, City of Westminster, SW1A 0AA, United Kingdom" lat="51.499100" lng="-0.121955" type="location" />
</markers>
```

**map.html**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>

<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"
        type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

var customIcons = {
  location: {
    icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_red.png',
    shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'
  }
};

function load() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(27.2500, 2.5200), 
            // world (27.2500, 2.5200), zoom 2
            // usa (39.6791686, -95.5335914), zoom 4
    zoom: 2,
    mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
  });
  var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

  // Change this depending on the name of your PHP file
  downloadUrl("locations.xml", function(data) {
    var xml = data.responseXML;
    var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
      var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
      var address = markers[i].getAttribute("address");
      var type = markers[i].getAttribute("type");
      var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
          parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
          parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
      var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + address;
      var icon = customIcons[type] || {};
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: point,
        icon: icon.icon,
        shadow: icon.shadow
      });
      //bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
    }
  });
}

function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html) {
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    //infoWindow.setContent(html);
    //infoWindow.open(map, marker);
  });
}

function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
  var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
      new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
      new XMLHttpRequest;

  request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (request.readyState == 4) {
      request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
      callback(request, request.status);
    }
  };

  request.open('GET', url, true);
  request.send(null);
}

function doNothing() {}

</script>
</head>

<body onLoad="load()">
  <div id="map" style="width: 1050px; height: 550px"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How do you expect us to replicate the problem with 2 entries in the xml file?  You say it works for that.  My suspicion is that there is a problem with your data somewhere around the 250th entry.

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you!  Turns out it had to do with using Excel to create a formula to generate the lines for locations.xml.  I needed to round to a smaller number of decimals and then it began working properly.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is there is a problem with your data somewhere around the 250th entry.